# Where does the "front page" fit in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I think I get the basic concepts of MVC, but I'm not sure where I should put my "home page"? By that I mean for example the page that would come up if you navigated to stackoverflow.com rather than something like stackoverflow.com/questions which has an obvious controller attached (the "questions" controller).

I have a function which determines what controller to use based on a GET variable, but I'm not quite sure what do do when that variable is missing. I was thinking of adding a define() for like a "default path" but I'm not sure what to use. The main page will fall in a category of pages, but will be its own separte entity. To use stackoverflow as the example, I could route the front page to the 'questions" controller, but don't know what to use as an action. "questions/frontpage" seems like a bad name to me.

Its odd, but I don't see this covered in any MVC tutorial online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a *home* controller, generally.

If you have basic routing set up in a bootstrap type file, just point a blank `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or similar to your home controller.

Answer (score 1):

most MVC frameworks map a controller without an "action" specified to the "index()" function within the controller, some kind of a default behavior.

in Kohana's case, a call to

```
http://mysite.com
```

is actually mapped to the "default controller" (specified in a configuration file, you can name the controller however you like) and an "index()"  function within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Most MVC frameworks have some kind of default route defined for the path '/'. You can call the controller whatever makes sense; if nothing else, then "main" or "default" work fine. I typically call the "front page" of any controller "index".

Comment: I'm not using a framework. Again using SO as example, there's a difference between "stackoverflow.com" and "stackoverflow.com/questions" but they're both "default" pages which show lists of questions. Maybe the front page needs to be its own controller, with just an "index' action?

Comment: Shit, I think I just made a dumb realization. Stackoverflow also has "tags" which are lists of questions, but are still separate.. of course tere would be a controller just for home! Thanks!

Comment: well how is your routing set up? With SO you simply have the two routes pointing to the same controller/action. You shoudl be able to do that easily. I mean if your home page needs completely seperate logic (which it does) then it may belong in its own separate controller (which as i mentioned in my answer, i usually call `core` or `default`).

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be anything. U normally use Symfony or Zend and i have a module/controller called `default` or `core` and generally speaking the home page is the `index` action in that module/controller. Then in my routing configuration i specify that as the default route using '/' or whatever as my routing URL.

Answer (score 0):

The default page defaults to "index.html". 
If you have an "index.html" in your root "www" directory this is the page that will be displayed if there is nothing but the web site address on the request url.

You can tweak the apache config file (not sure about ASP) to make another page or script the default, or, to make index.(php|jsp|*) your default.

Depends on circunstances but I would normally recomend you have a static "index.html" page which contains links to the dynamic parts of your website.